# Javascript onchange='this.size=0;' for select tag is not working in IE

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer

I have been trying to display a fixed number of items in the drop-down making it scroll able. For example the no. of items to be displayed is 8.

The code I am using is:

```
multiSelectOption = "<select style='position:absolute;z-index:1' name='noOfSameService' onmousedown='if(this.options.length>8){this.size=8;}' onchange='this.size=0;' onblur='this.size=0;' id='noOfSameService' >"+createMultiServiceOptions()+"</select>"
```

This is working fine in FireFox and Chrome, but in IE when ever the option is selected, it stops working, and reloads the page showing a message.
If onchange='this.size=0;' is omitted, then everything is working fine in IE, but when the option is selected, the list still appears until it is clicked out side the drop down.

A little suggestion could be a great help. I need solution for IE8+. Thanks in advance.

Update: I tried the following too with change() of JQuery:

```
multiSelectOption = "<select style='position:absolute;z-index:1' name='noOfSameService' onmousedown='if(this.options.length>6){this.size=6;}'   onblur='this.size=0;' id='noOfSameService' >"+createMultiServiceOptions()+"</select>";

$("#noOfSameService").change(function() {
            this.size = 1;
            this.blur();
        });
```

Comment: IE does not support onchange event very well. Use onclick event or use change() of JQuery. I recommend using jQuery to avoid these cross browser issues

Comment: It's not working for IE, but working fine for other browsers.